# Can I build my own focal reducer by reversing a teleconverter?

Tags: focal-length, diy, teleconverter

Would it be feasible to reverse a 1.4x teleconverter's optics into a cross-system lens mount adapter & have it function as a focal reducer?

For example, like this:

```
Camera    hacked adapter       Lens with 
 body  ←      w/           →    longer 
         reverse TC optics   registration
```

This would entail cannibalizing a 1.4x TC & mounting its optics backwards into a mount adapter.

Could it also sharpen the center of the field a scosche, by forcing optical concentration of the field, as well as gain a partial stop by intensifying the field?

If this is feasible, it might also be feasible for Tx/T2/T 135/35mm mount lenses,  assuming they were engineered with extra field to accommodate Nikon's long lens registration, when adapting to far shorter registration length/flange distance systems (basically anyone shorter than Leica R or Nikon F).

Plasticine / JB-Weld not included.

+----------------------------------

Addendum:

"Poor Man's Focal Reducer" at mflenses.com (a "manual-focus" lense afficionado site):

Entails some trial & error:

http://forum.mflenses.com/viewtopic.php?t=57639

Comment: Or you could just buy a metabones speedbooster - http://www.metabones.com/

Comment: Granted, but Metabones' stuff comes at a premium. And, Metabones doesn't make those for every imaginable cross-system scenario.

Comment: You might discover the resulting image circle doesn't completely cover the sensor, depending on the sensor size.

Comment: Real black-ring vignetting isn't necessarily a problem w/ a 24MP sensor, provided it doesn't realize too large a black ring around the image... As you point out, it's more likely with a larger sensor, but with a crop sensor (APS-C or Four-thirds) I might wager a better than even chance of either no, or normal, vignetting.

By gaining sharpness & 1 stop (assuming a 1.4x TC doublet) the crop option is surely opened up some, esp. considering mediocre lenses might actually be forced to resolve down below the sensor's circle of confusion.

Comment: Hmmm. 50mm f/1.8, 2 x TC , ... :-)

Comment: Thinking of f/0.9? 

Worse yet, vintage Nikkor F/1.4's can be had for $100, F/1.2's for $300. Mount one of those on a mirrorless body, hack the TC doublet into an adapter & you're a lowlight wizard ... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you could put reversed TC optics into a tube and use it as a focal reducer for shorter registration distance systems, in the process sharpening and intensifying the field. You could even give it a silly name like "lens turbo" or "speed booster" and sell loads of them!

The quality obtained by re-purposing an existing teleconverter for the task would be highly questionable as modern TCs are a long way from general purpose optics and are specifically designed to be paired with certain telephoto lenses.

Comment: I disagree, "lens turbo" sounds awesome. So awesome I am looking into it on Google right now.

Comment: Indeed. Or how 'bout "Optical Laxative." Faster, narrower, less grainy ...

Comment: I don't doubt there might prove some side-effects in image quality, especially at the corners. First find the proper TC match for a given lens & try that first. After that, then try various TC's fitting the body. 

Past that, perhaps onto Franken-lensing ... introducing field flatteners, coma reducers .. these are used in telescopy all the time, of varying magnitude to rectify simple defects in a telescope's main elements.

Comment: Wild conjecturing from hereon: The element diameter on the TC is close to the optics for 2" telescope eyepieces. Might work... :O

Comment: Please see my addendum to the original post. 

Another DIY effort using M42 lenses has shown this to not only feasible but demonstrated surprisingly good results (after some trial & error). 

The resulting configuration apparently is very susceptible to severe coma at low aperture, but at middle apertures of f/8 & up, the resulting resolution appeared to be quite good (looks like 100+ l/mm resolution).

Without coma correction such an adapter won't be general-purpose. If coma correction is feasible, then all the better.

Comment: Further reading indicates that "focal reducers" are also referred to as teleconverters, but of multipliers less than one, e.g. a "0.9 teleconverter." Since the smallest commonly available "normal" TC is a 1.4x, inverting it would yield a 0.714 multiplier.

Comment: This answer seems to have been written in jest, but it's wrong. Flipping a teleconverter around won't turn it into a focal reducer. Here are [sample images](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/105798/75526) to demonstrate what happens.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I build my own focal reducer by reversing a teleconverter?
>
> ... mounting its optics backwards into a mount adapter ...

Focal reducers and teleconverters are specialized lenses, and **flipping lenses around doesn't change their optical properties the way you want.** It would be nice if optics worked like that, but then someone would already be selling convertible tele-focal-converter-reducers.

Flipping lenses around will change the distance to the focal points on either side of the page (when drawing diagrams). However, the "[power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_power)" stays the same. Teleconverters and focal reducers have opposite powers (negative vs positive).

To demonstrate, here is an image taken with a 35/2.8 lens on a crop sensor body:

[image: Hansa]

Here is an image taken with the same lens and a teleconverter:

[image: Hansa + teleconverter]

Here is an image taken with the same lens and "reversed" teleconverter. In this case, the field of view is about the same, but with added vignetting. The image circle did get smaller, but *no* focal reduction.

[image: Hansa + "reverse" teleconverter]